# What's the terminology for this matrix relationship?

Tags: matrices, terminology, determinant, matrix-rank, pseudoinverse

I can't remember the proper terminology I heard long ago for the relationship between matrices like these two.

A and B are rank-deficient square matrices that cover independent subspaces of a transform (and I'm not even sure I phrased that correctly).  Their sum is full rank, and its inverse is the sum of the pseudo-inverses.

$|A|=|B|=0$

$AB=BA=0$

$\left(A+B\right)^{-1}=A^{\dagger}+B^{\dagger}$

Thanks!